# Is there a way that sendMessage(msg) returns until the msg has been processed?

Tags: android

In Windows SendMessage will block the call threading until the msg had been processed.
But in Android, it seemed that sendMessage returns just put the msg in message queue.
So, is there a way to do the same thing as Windows SendMessage in Android?

Comment: no, Messages are placed in the MessageQueue in async way

Answer (score 0):

I might have not mention my question clearly. What I really want is make Handler.sendMessage(msg) blocking the calling thread until the msg has been processed by Handler.handleMessage().
After searching and reading something about wait() and notify(), I accomplish that simply by using semaphore...
But anyway, thank you all, and Merry Christmas. :-)